Error_code: invalid_grant, error_description: AADSTS70000: The provided value for the input parameter 'refresh_token' - Bing ADS API
I am getting this error while I am fetching 'authorization_data'.  But it is running good in my staging and local environment but its not working in my production.
I have cross-checked my 'developer_token', 'client_id' and 'client secret'  multiple times. It is all good still I am still getting this error.
My code goes like below:

def find_customerid(shop_id, refresh_token):
       authorization_data = set_authorization(shop_id,None, None, refresh_token)
       customer_service = ServiceClient(service='CustomerManagementService', version=13, authorization_data=authorization_data, environment='production')


def set_authorization(shop_id,account_id, customer_id, refresh_token):
     authorization_data = AuthorizationData(
        account_id= account_id,
        customer_id= customer_id,
        developer_token= my_developer_token,
        authentication= OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant(
            client_id= my_client_id,
            client_secret=my_client_secret,
            redirection_uri=my_redirection_uri,
            )
        )
        authorization_data.authentication.request_oauth_tokens_by_refresh_token(refresh_token)
        return authorization_data


